# If $|f_1(z)| = |f_2(z)|$ on $|z| = 1$, how to prove $f_1(z) \equiv f_2(z)$ in $|z| < 1$.

Tags: complex-analysis

> $f_1(z),f_2(z)$ are holomorphic functions at $|z| \le 1$, in $|z| < 1$, $f_1(z), f_2(z)$ have no zero point both, and $f_1(0), f_2(0) > 0$.
>
> If $|f_1(z)| = |f_2(z)|$ on $|z| = 1$, prove $f_1(z) \equiv f_2(z)$ in $|z| < 1$.

I know when $f_1(z)=f_2(z)$ on $|z| = 1$, we can use Cauchy's integral formula, it is easy to do. But this, I have no idea.

Comment: The constant functions $1$ and $-1$ satisfy the first but not the second.  So you want to conclude $f_1(z) \equiv \alpha f_2(z)$ for some complex constant $\alpha$ with $|\alpha| = 1$.

Comment: $g=f_1/f_2$ and $1/g=f_2/f_1$ are holo, $|g|=|1/g|=1$ on $|z|=1$. Maximum modulus principle gives you they are constant. So $f_1=cf_2$ for some constant $c$ such that $|c|=1$.

Comment: Finally, since $0<f_1(0)/f_2(0)=c$ we get that $c$ is real and $=1$.

Comment: @MlazhinkaShungGronzalezLeWy Thank you, I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: @GEdgar Thank you, I know it with the help of both of you, Thank you.